# gitlab CI/CD seems to ignore dependency and stages

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm pretty sure this is a question about me not fully grasping the concept of the merge request event in gitlab CI/CD.

So a somewhat simplified version of my CI/CD configuration looks like this:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build

run-tests:
    image: node:lts
    stage: test
    before_script:
        - npm install
    script:
        - run_tests

build-branch:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  needs: ["run-tests"]
  script:
    - fancy_build_command
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

Thing is:
without the `needs`, `run-test` runs in parallel with build-branch whenever I push a commit to the MR branch (after the MR has been created). If I add the `needs`, they still run in parallel but the `build-branch` pipeline fails with

```
'build-branch' job needs 'run-tests' job, but 'run-tests' is not in any previous stage
```

I'm sure I may want to make the build step a manual step, but that doesn't really change the question much.

However the pipeline editor is totally happy validating my yml, and if I look at the visualisation it nicely shows the dependency.

If I add a rule

```
    rules:
      - when: on_success
```

to my test pipeline, two pipelines are executed in parallel for each commit: one consisting of only the test step, and another consisting of the test step followed by the build step (the latter being what I want to achieve).

What am I missing here? I guess there may be something wrong with my understanding of the `merge_request_event`. I guess if I add that requirement to `run-tests` this would work but my intention is to have that job run for every commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To archive your goal it is possible to use the following `gitlab-ci` file:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "test"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
```

How it works:

- If no merge request is created - after each push `branch pipeline` will run with job `test` only.
- If merge request is created - after each push `merge request pipeline` will run with both jobs - `test` and `build`. Job `build` will run upon successful completion of the job `test`.

Additional info:

- As it is written on the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html):

  > Merge request pipelines:
  >
  > - Do not run by default. The jobs in the CI/CD configuration file must be configured to run in merge request pipelines.
- You can find an example regarding how to switch workflow between `branch pipelines` and `merge request pipelines` in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines).

Comment: Oh I see, thanks!